# Using openMP with Cython: parallelising an inner loop

Tags: python, multithreading, cython

(as you will see I am not very familiar with concepts like the Python GIL and multithreading  IN PYTHON (or cython))

I have written a function in Cython that consists of a fragment of code with a double for loop where a function f is called repeatedly.

```
for i in range(I):
  for j in range(J):
    res=f(A[i],B[j])
```

I have a machine with 4 CPUs cores and I want to parallelise not the first but the second loop. 
I found [this wonderful website](http://www.perrygeo.com/parallelizing-numpy-array-loops-with-cython-and-mpi.html) but it does not treat the case of the inner loop and do not go into details. 
So in my opinion I can write:

```
for i in range(I):
  #In what case can I release the GIL safely ? Is that necessary at all ?
  with nogil, parallel(num_threads=4):
    for j in prange(J,shedule="dynamic"):
      res=f(A[i],B[j])
```

Would that work ? Do I have to put the with nogil outside of both loops so it doesn't run repeatedely into it releasing and "capturing" this GIL thing ? Could somebody explain to me how and what is the logic behind writing such statements so that I would be able to generalize to unseeen problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a time cost to releasing and recapturing the GIL and also a time cost to setting up a parallel loop. For this reason it's usually better to make the outermost loop the parallel one. However, if you have a good reason why you specifically want to parallelize the inner loop then it will work and hopefully the cost should be small compared to the real work contained in `f`.

Releasing the GIL prevents you from accessing Python variables and calling Python functions. Typed Cython variables, `cdef` functions and Cython memoryviews work fine. You'll get a small speed-up from putting the `with nogil:` as far out as possible. Therefore put it round the outer loop if possible, but if it isn't possible then it's OK where you've shown it.

It is necessary to release to GIL for a `prange` loop. If necessary you can then reclaim it inside the loop (`with gil`) but try to only do this for small fractions of the loop and only if needed (code that needs the GIL can't run in parallel with other code that needs the GIL).

The line `res=f(A[i],B[j])` is slightly odd for parallel code since only the `res` from the last loop would be saved. Typically you'd write into elements of an array (e.g. `res[i,j]=f(A[i],B[j])`). However, there may be good reason for doing it like you've shown...

Cython will (usually) warn you if you try to do something that requires the GIL so a good idea is to try it and see.

Comment: Thanks @DavidW definitely interesting answer ! Obviously there is a good reason for me not to parallelise the outer loop. I did not write the details of my code and the res stuff is silly. I will improve my question a bit. I upvoted and will accept it if it works !